# Filepath from SQL database not looping a BG image

Tags: php, css, sql, while-loop, global-variables

I have an Image uploaded to a folder with the filepath stored in a table along with other info (title, description). I would like this info looping inside a repeated div. Both other variables loop correctly, however the filepath variable needs to be used in a background URL and at the moment only echos the value of the last row. Thank you very much for your help, there has got to be a simple solution! -Sean

---

```html
<?php
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `program`");
 $values = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $globals['filepath'] = $row['filepath'];
 
 

echo "<div>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results


echo "<div class=wrapper3  >

<h2>" . $row['program_name'] . "</h2>
<p>" . $row['program_description'] . "</p>

</div>
<p>         </br>      </p>";

$globals['bgimage'] = $row['filepath'];

}
echo "</div>";


?>

<style type="text/css">
.wrapper3{

 width:85%;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:20px;
 height:auto;
 color:#FFF;

    background: url(/SMLC/<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo $globals['bgimage'];} ?>
) no-repeat; 
 background-size:cover;
 color:#000;
 height:250px;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#fff;
 border-radius:6px;
 border:1px solid #0FF;


}

</style>
<?php mysql_close();?>
```

Comment: the problem is, i think, you pass the first row, when you says: `$values = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

Comment: That is true but even when i remove that. It is still only echoing the last value..

Comment: see my answer. you need to remove the mysql_fetch_array outside from loop, remove the background property from wrapper3, and add the image as an inline style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the background from the `.wrapper3` in css, and add it to the element as an inline style.

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `program`");
echo "<div>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   //Creates a loop to loop through results
    $globals['filepath'] = $row['filepath'];
    echo "<div class='wrapper3' style=\"background: url('/SMLC/".$row["filepath"]."');\">
            <h2>" . $row['program_name'] . "</h2>
            <p>" . $row['program_description'] . "</p>
        </div>
        <p></br></p>";
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

**NOTE:** Use mysqli functions or PDO instead of mysql functions, since, mysql functions are deprecated.